# How to set ExecutionPolicy: access to registry key denied

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I'm running Windows Server 2008 as admin and I tried to set ExecutionPolicy as Remotesigned for PowerShell v2 like this:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

But I got this error:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft
.PowerShell' is denied.
At line:1 char:20
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy <<<<  RemoteSigned
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyComma
   nd
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Right click on Powershell shortcut and choose 'Run as Administrator'

Comment: Also note that if you have a 64-bit OS you need to set the execution policy for both the 32-bit and 64-bit version of PowerShell.

Comment: You don't need to run it as admin, just run it with `-Scope CurrentUser` as Janus answer suggests

Answer (score 16):

Stephen Jennings in reply to the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647429/powershell-on-windows-7-set-executionpolicy-for-regular-user) on StackOverflow:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

This will set the execution policy for the current user (stored in HKEY_CURRENT_USER) rather than the local machine (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE).

Comment: Thanks. This is the correct answer, not everyone has administrator privileges, but this still works.

Answer (score 4):

In case "Run as Administrator" doesn't work for you(didn't for me at first) or if you want a permanent solution, I found a fix by adding the permissions directly to the windows registry. After doing this when I called get-ExecutionPolicy it no longer came back restricted.

It's the equivalent of set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned, with it actually working.

Wrote about it here:
http://kyleclegg.com/powershell/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the only solution to this error that worked for me was to run regedt32 & drill down to the key then change the permissions for users from read to full control. Local permissions on the server take precedent to the domain admin rights.

Comment: Not really a good answer, given the other two answers already present...